# -fsanitize=address duplicates inline strings. Is this intended behavior or a compiler issue?

Tags: c++, sanitizer

In our codebase we expect that strings only exist once in the compiled binary. I observe that

> -fsanitize=address

can generate duplicated strings in the executable. This breaks our code.

The following godbolt example demonstrates the issue https://godbolt.org/z/G5edcnr5e.

My question is if this an intended behavior or a compiler issue?

Comment: It doesn't seem like it's `-fsanitize=address` that does this. Here is a different example: https://godbolt.org/z/PeG6sxYff

Comment: On further experimentation, this seems like a GCC bug. Here: <https://godbolt.org/z/cE16ev71c> the pointers-to-string-literals have the same address, but when read produce a different address